# Can I put a Button in a RichTextBox in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox

I would like to allow users to put a System.Windows.Controls.Button in the System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox. The button would do a pre-defined thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. It's called an InlineUIContainer you can do something like this to get it working. Although it doesn't save it into the Xaml

```
var p = new Paragraph();
var inlineUIContainer = new InlineUIContainer() { Child = new Button() { Content = "This is a Button!" } };
p.Inlines.Add(inlineUIContainer);
_richTextBox.Blocks.Add(p);
```